# bootstrap 3 input-group in panel heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have a panel. In the panel-heading, I want to put a form with input-group. In the HTML below, in the input-group, I have a form to perform a search. In that form I have an input-group with a textbox and button/submit.  When the input-group is displayed, it puts the search button on the line below and not beside the textbox. How can I get everything to show on line line?

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:50px;">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;List
      <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
        <div class="input-group" style="width:140px;">
          <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/index.php/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="R3GjM2xVYzboRQzaTKLYQSI2rpjUWYqQoVkNLsBp">
            <input id="stockno" class="form-control" maxlength="12" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" value="">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
            <li><b>Sort</b></li>
            <li>Col A</li>
            <li>Col B</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Col A</td>
        <td>Col B</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
              <tr>
          <td colspan="2">No results found.</td>
        </tr>
                  </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Sample code:
https://www.codeply.com/go/8s0jfWbmB4

This is what it does:
[image]

This is what I want but don't know how as a form:
[image]

Comment: 'here's solution to this' i've tested it:
`<div class="input-group">
                <input id="stockno" class="form-control" maxlength="12" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" value="">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
           </span>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the `form-inline` class to the form element like below:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="http://localhost/index.php/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="R3GjM2xVYzboRQzaTKLYQSI2rpjUWYqQoVkNLsBp">
   <input id="stockno" class="form-control" maxlength="12" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" value="">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
   </span>
</form>
```

That's what the documentation on the Bootstrap website says to do anyways:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms

Comment: Thanks for response, but unfortunately this does not work.